# Dependency injection - Cannot resolve method 'select' in 'WeldContainer' Error

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I try to add dependency injection to my app, but I got the error   Cannot resolve method 'select' in 'WeldContainer'

This is my relevan code:

```
import  org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;
import  org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;


public class MainApp {

    private  static WeldContainer container = new Weld().initialize();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AlgorithmRunner algorithmRunner =container.select(AlgorithmRunner.class).get();
        algorithmRunner.runAlgorithms();
    }

}
```

The system does not support the select method.
What can be the reason and how can I resolve it.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: which build tool you're using (maven, gradle, ...)? Adding dependency declaration might help

Comment: What do you mean exactly, the project structure modules dependencies tab?